# Need to increase height and width of circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to increase circle height and width to double. But it's not working. Please suggest me where I put the error in the code. I have no idea about the value of `r`. Please help me to update the value of `r`.

Here is my sample code.

```js
var time = 10;
var initialOffset = '440';
var i = 1
var r = $(".circle_animation").attr("r");
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  $('.circle_animation').css(
    'stroke-dashoffset',
    initialOffset - (i * (initialOffset / time) * (r / 69.85699))
  );
  $('h2').text(i);
  if (i == time) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  i++;
}, 1000);
```

```css
    .item {
      position: relative;
      float: left;
    }

    .item h2 {
      text-align: center;
      position: absolute;
      line-height: 125px;
      width: 100%;
    }

    svg {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }

    .circle_animation {
      stroke-dasharray: 440;
      /* this value is the pixel circumference of the circle */
      stroke-dashoffset: 440;
      transition: all 1s linear;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item html">
  <h2>0</h2>
  <svg width="160" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
         <g>
          <title>Layer 1</title>
          <circle id="circle" class="circle_animation" r="69.85699" cy="81" cx="81" stroke-width="8" stroke="#6fdb6f" fill="none"/>
         </g>
        </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: you are right on the approach, but a couple values need to be updated because of mathematical rules. good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you guessed, you have to change the value of `r` to change the radius.

If we look at the javascript code:

```
    var r = $(".circle_animation").attr("r");
```

It means that `r` is the value of the html attribute `r` of the element with class name `circle_animation`.

If we then look at the html markup:

```
    <circle id="circle" class="circle_animation" r="69.85699" cy="81" cx="81" stroke-width="8" stroke="#6fdb6f" fill="none"/>
```

we see that r is set to 69.85699 on the circle with class name `circle_animation`

After that you have to remember that since your drawing a larger circle, you will also have to double both the size of the svg and the stroke-dasharray and stroke-dashoffset (these values are supposed to be 2*2*PI*r for this animation).

Here is your example with doubled radius as you requested:

```js
var time = 10;
var initialOffset = '440';
var i = 1
var r = $(".circle_animation").attr("r");
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    $('.circle_animation').css(
        'stroke-dashoffset',
        initialOffset-(i*(initialOffset/time)*(r/139.71398))
    );
    $('h2').text(i);
    if (i == time) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    i++;  
}, 1000);
```

```css
.item {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.item h2 {
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 125px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 60px;
}

svg {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.circle_animation {
  stroke-dasharray: 878; /* this value is the pixel circumference of the circle */
  stroke-dashoffset: 878;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item html">
    <h2>0</h2>
    <svg width="320" height="320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <g>
      <title>Layer 1</title>
      <circle id="circle" class="circle_animation" r="139.71398" cy="162" cx="162" stroke-width="8" stroke="#6fdb6f" fill="none"/>
```

Comment: Please run the code and you see circle break after count 6.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to also double the value in setInterval. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

your radius is `69.85699` on the circle. lets consider `70` for simplicity.

double will be `140`, circumference of this circle would be `880`
now your `cx` and `cy` should also consider the offset/width of the stroke.
so, `140 + (8/2)`

most other calculations are simple as you have already done them.

```js
var time = 10;
var initialOffset = '880';
var i = 1
var r = $(".circle_animation").attr("r");
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    $('.circle_animation').css(
        'stroke-dashoffset',
        initialOffset-(i*(initialOffset/time)*(r/140))
    );
    $('h2').text(i);
    if (i == time) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    i++;  
}, 1000);
```

```css
.item {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.item h2 {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 265px;
    width: 100%;
}

svg {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.circle_animation {
  stroke-dasharray: 880; /* this value is the pixel circumference of the circle */
  stroke-dashoffset: 880;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item html">
    <h2>0</h2>
    <svg width="300" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <g>
      <title>Layer 1</title>
      <circle id="circle" class="circle_animation" r="140" cy="144" cx="144" stroke-width="8" stroke="#6fdb6f" fill="none"/>
     </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this, Check this fiddle and code https://jsfiddle.net/rmcej7vk/

HTML

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item html">
  <h2>0</h2>
  <svg width="320" height="320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
         <g>
          <title>Layer 1</title>
          <circle id="circle" class="circle_animation" r="139.7139" cy="162" cx="162" stroke-width="8" stroke="#6fdb6f" fill="none"/>
         </g>
        </svg>
</div>
```

JS

```
var time = 10;
var initialOffset = '880';
var i = 1
var r = $(".circle_animation").attr("r");
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  $('.circle_animation').css(
    'stroke-dashoffset',
    initialOffset - (i * (initialOffset / time) * (r / 139.7139))
  );
  $('h2').text(i);
  if (i == time) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  i++;
}, 1000);
```

CSS

```
.item {
      position: relative;
      float: left;
    }

    .item h2 {
      text-align: center;
      position: absolute;
      line-height: 250px;
      width: 100%;
    }

    svg {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }

    .circle_animation {
      stroke-dasharray: 880;
      /* this value is the pixel circumference of the circle */
      stroke-dashoffset: 880;
      transition: all 1s linear;
    }
```